# Can a single Secret be represented as a single file?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes (aren't we all?).

Can a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), consisting of course of keys and values, be represented as a *single* file when used by a container?

I understand that normally a Secret, when [mounted by a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod), is essentially a directory.  I was wondering if there was some syntactic sugar or other construct that I'm missing that could represent it as, say, a Java `Properties` file, whose keys would be the secret's keys, and whose values would be the secret's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible currently. The only way to get around this is to have a key value pair where the value is a base64 encoded JSON object.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  conf.json: eyJrZXkiOiAidmFsdWUiLCAia2V5MiI6ICJ2YWx1ZTIifQ==
```

The `conf.json` value is just:

```
echo -n '{"key": "value", "key2": "value2"}' | base64
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, that's the workaround I'm using now.

Answer (score 0):

For others visiting, this now possible using the `stringData` field of a `Secret` definition.

So for this example, I have a secret called `environment-secrets`. This secret contains a single key called `env.yml`, which is itself a YAML file containing a number of `key=value` parings. I want to mount this secret onto my pods at `/credentials/env/env.yml`.

Firstly I define the object definition for the secret as follows in a file called `environment-secret.yml`:

```
- kind: Secret
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: environment-secret
  type: Opaque
  stringData:
    env.yml: |-
      db_host=my-db.host
      db_user=db-user
      db_password=db-pass
```

I then create the secret using `kubectl create -f environment-secret.yml`. Upon creation, the values in the `env.yml` `stringData` field are converted into a `env.yml` entry in the `data` field of the secret.

Next I update my `PodSpec` to mount the secret at my desired location. So I firstly define the secret as a volume:

```
volumes:
   - name: environment-secret
     secret:
     optional: false
      secretName: environment-secret
```

And then update the `mountPoints` to mount this secret at my preferred location within my containers:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /credentials/env
  name: environment-secret
```

After this I have a file on my container at `/credentials/env/env.yml` that contains my `key=value` pairings.